# If you subscribe to JC's ruling, are enemies attacked by a conjured creature considered "targets" of the conjuration spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, summoning

According to Jeremy Crawford the "Dragon's Breath" spell also [targets the creatures hit by the exhalation](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/944272988983062528), and [Green-Flame Blade targets two creatures](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/663510873449762816).

My understanding is that according to JC, any creature "affected" by a spell is considered "targeted" by it.

Suppose I subscribe to JC's ruling.

I cast a conjure spell (say, Conjure Animals). If my summoned creature attacks an enemy, is that enemy considered a "target" of the conjure spell?

Comment: This might be better phrased as 'if you subscribe to JC's ruling, are enemies attacked by conjured creatures considered targets of the spell', because the only real answer to this is no, but JC's tweet is probably a good example of why they are no longer official.

Comment: Good point. I thought JC's ruling was well accepted, but it is clear it is not.

Comment: I'm not sure we can substantively change the question to that as it invalidates Smart_TJ's answer which is based on the rules and not on JC's tweets. You may need to roll back and ask the new Tweet-based question separately since there is an answer already that doesn't make the assumption you now require.

Comment: I think the JC-based question is unanswerable since we cannot know JC's ruling on one thing based on something else.

Comment: Might just be easier to ask "are characters attacked by conjured creatures considered targets of the conjuration spell?" and state that you're interested in the rationale.  Leave the JC references in a background or references section of the question body.

Comment: @GcL Should I ask a broader question, and just ignore answers that don't fit with my (now hidden) assumption?

Comment: @kviiri Jeremy's interpretation of the Targeting rule has its own rationale that well documented in multiple tweets and a podcast. I don't see how my question is necessarily unanswerable.

Comment: @Merudo Unless he's explicitly stated it, any generalization is just guesswork.

Comment: I think this is a fair question—but I don’t think we can or should handle it. Realistically, unless Crawford addresses this question himself, there is no real way to justify either answer—and thus this question will just invite bad answers (speculation). We’ve been down this road before, it doesn’t work out.

Answer (score 3):

No, the conjured creature was the target of the spell, as the spell creates the creature. Any creature attacked by a conjured creature doesn't just become the target of the spell that conjured the creature, because they aren't being directly affected by the spell. Being affected by a spell means that if, say, [*color spray*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/color-spray) was cast, and the 15 ft. cone included 2 creatures.

Those 2 creatures are considered targets, because they are **directly** influenced. After that, anything they interact with in any way doesn't then also become targets of color spray. If a spell creates, conjures, or summons something, unless the spell says otherwise, anything that that object, character, or creature interacts with in any way does not become the target, as the spell is simply creating that thing, not targeting anything that that thing interacts with. That's just not how spells work.

Comment: Why does the spell Dragon's Breath targets the creatures hit by the breath, but Conjure Animals doesn't target the creatures hit by the conjured beasts?

Comment: because conjured beast's target is the conjured creature. Anything it interacts with isn't directly influenced by the spell. I just finished editing to make the answer a bit better, also dragon breath isn't a spell btw

Comment: @Smart_TJ It's a new spell in Xanthar's Guide to Everything.

Comment: oh, I thought he was referencing the Dragonborn trait, never mind on that part, sorry, that's breath weapon now that i think about it

Comment: @Merudo as has been stated [on your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147231/can-the-dragons-breath-spell-damage-enemies-with-no-clear-path-to-the-caster#comment375880_147231), JC's tweets aren't *official* and thus aren't hard-set rules. Assuming everything based on that one linked tweet are *the* rules and *the* way everything should be isn't likely to end well.

Comment: As much as I want to agree with this answer, you should really add some sources and quotes to back some of this up. And a small discussion on JCs tweets being unofficial and sometimes wrong wouldn't be amiss here either I think.

Comment: OP has made a big change to their question asking that answers assume JC's tweet is correct and to use it in determining an answer. You may want to either make a change here, or post a comment on the question.

Answer (score -2):

### No. Summoning spells behave differently than other spells.

If we subscribe to Jeremy Crawford's ruling, we need to take into account [this tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1009573805415489537):

> A rakshasa's Limited Magic Immunity offers no protection against a summoned creature. The creature's presence is a spell effect. The creature itself is not a spell effect.

The conjured creature itself is not a spell effect, and therefore the attacks of the conjured creature are not spell effects either.

As a result, the spell does not target the enemies attacked by the summoned creature.

Comment: Doesn't this directly oppose the tweet you presented in the question? Which tweet takes priority?